# fetch different profile based on props condition react

Tags: reactjs, header, fetch, conditional-statements

in my app you log in with the user id, the app redirects you to your profile (fetched by a given api) every user has different authorization keys to perform the fetch, what I want to do is to change the API headers with the condition of the id:
ex)
id1 has auth key: abc
id2 has auth key: def
id3 has auth key: ghi

if I have to fetch the profile of id1 I need auth key: abs in the headers

id is given to the component as props

I tried in different ways, if-else statement, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please let me know, header means API header  or page header?. if you looking to change page header then react helmet is way to go.

Comment: API header with the right authorization key for that specific user id

Comment: Can you please create codesandbox url with your code, it will be easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

If by auth key you refer to token, then this issue is solved from backend.
You just check if the token is valid, you return that data.
If not , throw an error.

In your React app, do smth like that:

```js
useEffect(()=>{

try{
//Make request to profiles endpoint
}
catch(error){
//Redirect to login page
}
},[])
```

Comment: the token needs to be hard coded

Comment: Then hard code it in backend and give it to user once they login!
@Claudia